# Console class ReadPassword

Tags: java

```
String pw = c.readPassword("%s", "pw: ");
System.out.println("got " +pw); 
String name = c.readLine("%s", "name: "); 
System.out.println(" got ", name);
```

If the user types `fido` when prompted for a password, and then responds `bob` when prompted for a name,what is the result?

A. pw: got fido name: bob got bob

B. pw: fido got fido name: bob got bob

C. pw: got fido name: bob got bob

D. pw: fido got fido name: bob got bob

E. Compilation fails.

F. An exception is thrown at runtime.

Answer is E

According to me answer is E but i thought that in console you cannot `readPassword` in `String` because `char[]` is more safe. But SCJP book says its because you can't pass stings like this in

```
System.out.println(" got ", name);
```

" : i.e. using "," .  I agree with book , but i want to know , if we write

```
System.out.println("got" + name);
```

it will work fine? and whats the output? Why `char[]` is not used instead of `String`?

Comment: How can compilation fail when user is entering values? Is this a riddle or what?

Comment: "_if we write ... it will work fine? and whats the output?_" You can try that on your own and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

user2985842 you are right it has two errors
**1) As you said this line**

```
String pw = c.readPassword("%s", "pw: ");
```

contains error, readPassword() returns char[] but the lvalue is string

**2) As they said  this line**

```
System.out.println(" got ", name);
```

contains error ,it must have been

```
System.out.println(" got "+ name);
```